# Rails Routes With Query Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Not really sure the terminology involved, I didn't find anything searching but if someone can point me in the right direction I'll take another look.

I have a controller called Journals.  I would like to have a date optionally part of the URL.  If the user doesn't specify a date, they get today.  If there is a date specified, then it is used.  URLs would look like:

```
localhost:3000/journals/7/
localhost:3000/journals/7/2013-01-22/
```

The first would show Today's contents.  The second would show contents from the Jan 22.

I started with this route:

```
match '/journals/:id(/:date)', to: 'journals#show'
```

And a corresponding Controller

```
class JournalsController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if params[:date]
        @date = Date.parse(params[:date])
      else 
        @date = Date.today
      end
  end  
end
```

And this works fine, but how can I generate URLs using the url helpers?  I tried this:

```
<%= link_to "< Yesterday", journal_path(id: @user, date: @date.yesterday) %>
```

Which seems to actually work fine, but it gives me a url like this:

```
localhost:3000/journals/7?date=2013-01-22
```

instead of:

```
localhost:3000/journals/7/2013-01-22
```

How can I keep the URLs consistently built like  /journals/:id/:date

If there is a better approach please let me know.

Comment: actually, it should work. looks like you have `resources :journals`  in your routes.rb or something that conflicts with your current route.

Comment: please show your routes.rb

Comment: what about not using helper but a pure url string?

Comment: for complicated routes, you have to use url_for or polimorphic_path

Comment: I've been trying a few different things.  Right now I've got `scope "/:user_id(/:date)" do resource :journal end` and it seems to be working like I want.  The url helper builds the URLs as `localhost:3000/7/2013-01-22/journal`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in routes:

```
 resources :journals
 match '/journals/:id(/:date)' => 'journals#show', :constraints => { :date => /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ }, :as => "journals_date"
```